# Flutter build error: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException in path_provider_android

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm encountering an issue while building my Flutter application. When attempting to build the project, I'm getting the following warnings:

```
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
```

But more importantly, an error is preventing a successful build:

```
ERROR:E:\NewApp\third_app\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
```

This error seems to be related to path_provider_android and occurs during the `:app:mergeDexDebug` task. I'm using Flutter with a specific version of the Android Gradle Plugin (7.3.0).

Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this error and get the project to compile successfully?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Did you found a solution for your problem? I am experiencing an similar error for an cordova application.